# How do take an object from 2.8 and work on it in 2.79b?

Tags: export, import, versions

I'm trying to import the .dae file of a project I exported from my 2.8 installation, into my 2.79b installation. The object will import fine, but the textures get all messed up.

Here is the material I created in 2.8:
[image: Here is the material I created in 2.8]

Here is how it renders when I import it into 2.79b:
[image: Here is how it renders when I import it into 2.79b]

Here is the image I am using for the material:
[image: Here is the image I am using for the material]

Comment: Which textures do you mean? 2.8 is not fully back-compatible with older versions due to multiple changes. Image files from disk used as textures should be imported fine. Materials created in 2.8 won't necessarily work

Comment: @MrZak i'm trying to import a texture that is an image from disk.

Comment: @MrZak my mistake! i was on mobile so couldn't add image examples. is this more clear?

Comment: Second screenshot shows object imported into Blender Render engine which isn't compatible with new Blender 2.8 per se. Try to make render engines the same first i.e. switch to Cycles